# Gizmo types in blender 2.8

Tags: python

So, in Blender 2.8 avialable Gizmo Widgets(bpy.types.Gizmo, bpy.types.GizmoGroup).
i am tring to find out how to use different type of widgets(gizmos) but cant find any information about them.

Here is standart example:

```
# Example of a group that edits a single property
# using the predefined gizmo arrow.
#
# Usage: Select a light in the 3D view and drag the arrow at it's rear
# to change it's energy value.
#
import bpy
from bpy.types import (
    GizmoGroup,
)


class MyLightWidgetGroup(GizmoGroup):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_GGT_light_test"
    bl_label = "Test Light Widget"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_options = {'3D', 'PERSISTENT'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        ob = context.object
        return (ob and ob.type == 'LIGHT')

    def setup(self, context):
        # Arrow gizmo has one 'offset' property we can assign to the light energy.
        ob = context.object
        mpr = self.gizmos.new("GIZMO_GT_arrow_3d")
        mpr.target_set_prop("offset", ob.data, "energy")
        mpr.matrix_basis = ob.matrix_world.normalized()
        mpr.draw_style = 'BOX'

        mpr.color = 1.0, 0.5, 0.0
        mpr.alpha = 0.5

        mpr.color_highlight = 1.0, 0.5, 1.0
        mpr.alpha_highlight = 0.5

        self.energy_widget = mpr

    def refresh(self, context):
        ob = context.object
        mpr = self.energy_widget
        mpr.matrix_basis = ob.matrix_world.normalized()


bpy.utils.register_class(MyLightWidgetGroup)
```

I want to find out wich types i can set to:

```
mpr = self.gizmos.new("GIZMO_GT_arrow_3d")
```

and what properties(and types of them) this gizmo will have.
Any ideas?

Comment: For now, think instead of guessing and investigating how builtin gizmos works, i think is better way to use custom gizmos like in "gizmo_custom_geometry.py" in Templates.
This way one can have more control with widget shape and transform manipulations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the great thing about blender is that when something is not documented you can just look at the source. :)

Here are the ones I've found (untested):

#### `GIZMO_GT_arrow_2d`

#### `GIZMO_GT_arrow_3d`

- **props**:

  - `offset`
- **draw_style**:

  - `NORMAL` | `CROSS` | `BOX`| `CONE`
- **transform**:

  - `INVERT`| `CONSTRAIN`

#### `GIZMO_GT_blank_3d`

#### `GIZMO_GT_button_2d`

- **props**:

  - `icon` | `shape`| `show_drag`
- **draw_style**:

  - `OUTLINE` | `BACKDROP`| `HELPLINE`

#### `GIZMO_GT_cage_2d`

- **props**:

  - `dimensions`
- **draw_style**:

  - `BOX` | `CIRCLE`

#### `GIZMO_GT_cage_3d`

#### `GIZMO_GT_dial_3d`

#### `GIZMO_GT_move_3d`

#### `GIZMO_GT_primitive_3d`

#### `GIZMO_GT_value_2d`

- **props**:

  - `offset`

#### `VIEW3D_GT_navigate_rotate`

#### `GIZMO_GT_mesh_preselect_elem_3d`

- **props**:

  - `object_index` | `vert_index`| `edge_index` | `face_index`

#### `GIZMO_GT_mesh_preselect_edgering_3d`

#### `VIEW3D_GT_ruler_item`

I'm actually working on custom gizmos so I'll update this answer to document my findings.