# Drawing simple non interactive gizmos in the 3DView

Tags: python

For some tool I am working, I would like to draw some simple non interactive gizmo (Preferably in the shape of a “+”) in front of vertices my mouse is currently over, and I was wondering what solution I would have to do such thing in Blender with Python.

I already did some googling and found about the `bpy.types.GizmoGroup`, but when it comes to the actual availables Gizmo types/Gizmo identifier, the documentation is scarce, I only found this:
[Gizmo types in blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131685/gizmo-types-in-blender-2-8)

And none of the seemingly available gizmo types would match what I am looking for. Plus even if some of them would have a visual style that could work, they have some interactivity that I do not want.

Are there some other solutions do draw/render simple non interactive gizmos/ui elements in the 3DView?

Comment: Replying to my own old question. 
I went back recently to blender, and I found a solution to this issue in the following youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgrgEoNFNsA
It explains how to draw simple shapes in the 3DView using OpenGL. This is down via an operator, so it draws while the operator is active. I will post a proper reply with code sample later one.